# Using Ansible to stop service that might not exist

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible `2.6.1`.

I am trying to ensure that certain service is not running on target hosts.
Problem is that the service might not exist at all on some hosts. If this is the case Ansible fails with error because of missing service. Services are run by `Systemd`.

Using service module:

```
  - name: Stop service
    service:
      name: '{{ target_service }}'
      state: stopped
```

Fails with error `Could not find the requested service SERVICE: host`

Trying with command module:

```
 - name: Stop service
   command: service {{ target_service }} stop
```

Gives error: `Failed to stop SERVICE.service: Unit SERVICE.service not loaded.`

I know I could use `ignore_errors: yes` but it might hide real errors too.

An other solution would be having 2 tasks. One checking for existance of service and other that is run only when first task found service but feels complex.

Is there simpler way to ensure that service is stopped and avoid errors if the service does not exists?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Better focus on knowing what's running where.

Comment: This is not XY problem. Details are out of scope for this question but in this case cannot predict on which hosts the service is running. (Number of hosts running the service and which hosts should be running it is decided dynamically depending on the host load and number clients consuming the service.) To run a maintenance operation safely the said service must no be running. The maintenance operation needs to be run on all hosts whatever the service exists there or not so it makes sense to ensure that the service is not running any of the target hosts.

Comment: Depending on your service you can create a task that checks if the package for that service is installed and then stop the service only in case it exists.

Comment: The easiest way to make sure, that a service is stopped and keeps being stopped, is uninstalling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will register the module output in `service_stop`; if the module execution's standard output does not contain `"Could not find the requested service"` AND the service fails to stop based on return code, the module execution will fail. Since you did not include the entire stack trace I am assuming the error you posted is in the standard output, you may need to change slightly based on your error.

```
- name: Stop service
  register: service_stop
  failed_when: 
    - '"Could not find the requested service" not in service_stop.stdout'
    - service_stop.rc != 0
  service:
    name: '{{ target_service }}'
    state: stopped
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the following steps:

```
- name: Get the list of services
  service_facts:

- name: Stop service
  systemd:
    name: <service_name_here>
    state: stopped
  when: "'<service_name_here>.service' in services"
```

`service_facts` could be called once in the gathering facts phase.

Answer (score 9):

Same solution as @ToughKernel's but use `systemd` to manage service.

```yaml
- name: disable ntpd service
  systemd:
    name: ntpd
    enabled: no
    state: stopped
  register: stop_service
  failed_when:
    - stop_service.failed == true
    - '"Could not find the requested service" not in stop_service.msg'
    # the order is important, only failed == true, there will be
    # attribute 'msg' in the result
```

Comment: flawless. worked perfectly on v2.12.7!

Comment: This works like a dream with Ansible 2.9.7.

Comment: Also seems to work with a `with_items` loop.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there isn't simpler way to ensure that service is stopped. Ansible *service* module doesn't check service's existence. Either (1) more then one task, or (2) command that check service's existence is needed. The command would be OS specific. For example for FreeBSD

```
command: "service -e | grep {{ target_service }} && service {{ target_service }} stop"
```

Answer (score 2):

Same solution as Vladimir's, but for Ubuntu (systemd) and with better state handling:

```yaml
- name: restart {{ target_service }} if exists
  shell: if systemctl is-enabled --quiet {{ target_service }}; then systemctl restart {{ target_service }} && echo restarted ; fi
  register: output
  changed_when: "'restarted' in output.stdout"
```

It produces 3 states:

- service is absent or disabled — `ok`
- service exists and was restarted — `changed`
- service exists and restart failed — `failed`

Answer (score 0):

When the service module fails, check if the service that needs to be stopped is installed at all. That is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65748512/1268949), but avoids the rather lengthy gathering of service facts unless necessary.

```
- name: Stop a service
  block:
    - name: Attempt to stop the service
      service:
        name:  < service name >
        state: stopped
  rescue:
    - name: Get the list of services
      service_facts:

    - name: Verify that Nagios is not installed
      assert:
        that:
          - "'< service name >.service' not in services"
```